# Why is Keras Tokenizer Texts To Sequences Returning The Same Value For All Texts?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to create a Keras LSTM that will classify words as either 0 or 1. However, the network returns a value close to zero despite whatever text I enter. I have narrowed the problem down to an issue related to the Keras tokenizer. I have included a debugging print statement and commented the `model.predict()` code to test this issue. All the words return the array `[[208]]`.

*Code below*

```
from builtins import len

from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import layers
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import enchant
import re

d = enchant.Dict("en_US")

df = pd.read_csv('sentiments.csv')
df.columns = ["label", "text"]
x = df['text'].values
y = df['label'].values

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = \
    train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=123)

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=100)

tokenizer.fit_on_texts(x)
xtrain = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_train)
xtest = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_test)

vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1

maxlen = 10
xtrain = pad_sequences(xtrain, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)
xtest = pad_sequences(xtest, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)

print(x_train[3])
print(xtrain[3])

embedding_dim = 50
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Embedding(input_dim=(vocab_size+1),
                           output_dim=embedding_dim,
                           input_length=maxlen))
model.add(layers.LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.LSTM(units=10))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(8))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy",
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(xtrain, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=16, verbose=False)

loss, acc = model.evaluate(xtrain, y_train, verbose=False)
print("Training Accuracy: ", acc)
loss, acc = model.evaluate(xtest, y_test, verbose=False)
print("Test Accuracy: ", acc)

text_input = str(input("Enter a word for analysis: "))

if d.check(text_input):
    word_Arr = []
    word_Arr.append(text_input)
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(word_Arr)
    word_final = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(word_Arr)
    word_final_final = np.asarray(word_final)

    print(word_final_final)

    # newArr = np.zeros(shape=(6, 10))
    # newArr[0] = word_final_final

    # print(model.predict(newArr))
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You always refit your `Tokenizer` instance:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=100)

tokenizer.fit_on_texts(x)
```

with the newly inputted word in itself:

```
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(word_Arr)
```

So your tokens you created, with which you trained your model will be deleted and your newly fitted `Token` instance will tokenize your word based on the tokenization based on the word you entered.

**Example:**

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=100)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(["dog, cat, horse"])
ext_input = str(input("Enter a word for analysis: "))

word_Arr = []
word_Arr.append(text_input)

# here is your problem!!!
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(word_Arr)

word_final = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(word_Arr)
word_final_final = np.asarray(word_final)

print(word_final_final)
```

**Out:**

```
Enter a word for analysis: dog
[[1]]
Enter a word for analysis: cat
[[1]]
```

**Commenting out the problematic code part:**

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=100)

tokenizer.fit_on_texts(["dog, cat, horse"])
ext_input = str(input("Enter a word for analysis: "))

word_Arr = []
word_Arr.append(text_input)

# commenting out your problem!!!
# tokenizer.fit_on_texts(word_Arr)

word_final = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(word_Arr)
word_final_final = np.asarray(word_final)

print(word_final_final)
```

**Out**

```
Enter a word for analysis: cat
[[2]]
Enter a word for analysis: dog
[[1]]
```